# How to calculate Over Posted Speed Limit on highway using lat,long in here map

Tags: here-api

I have latitude and longitude where my car is driving on highway. I want to know whether my car speed is greater than highway speed where I am driving

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the simple Routing API(used for routing usecases) or Fleet Telematics API(used for complex routing problems like trucks).

**Routing API:** The below example provides the speed limits in a particular route. You can check this against your car speed limit to verify if you are driving within limits. Read more about the api in Here developer site - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-get-route.html

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=41.69758,-87.78397&waypoint1=41.70056,-87.77429&mode=fastest;car&storage=readonly&linkAttributes=speedLimit&app_code=yyyyy&app_id=xxxx&representation=linkPaging
```

**Fleet Telematics API:** You can get the speedlimit information along a route using this api as well. Here provides numerous examples on how to do this in https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples site. Just login with your Here credentials and search for speed. You can take a look at the source code there. You can also read more about this api in Here website https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/index.html

Hope you find these useful!Happy Coding!

Comment: I am getting response with key "speedLimit":31.3888893 . is this indicates highway speed limit ?

Comment: If the link is a highway then yes. But speedLimit is provided for almost all roads FC1-4